# Is there any way through which we can update List records based on specified condition in C#, any customized method will also work except loop

Tags: c#, list, collections

```
lstStudents.First(m => m.Passed == "").PassoutYear= CurrentYear;
```

is there any other way to update records in bulk like the above statement which updates on the first record in list.

Comment: Why? foreach loop is not good enough ?

Comment: A loop is *exactly* how you would do this.  You might abstract it behind a method call, but if you want to perform an operation on every element in a collection then fundamentally at some point there *must* be a loop iterating over that collection.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var student in lstStudents.Where(m => m.Passed == ""))
{
    student.PassoutYear = CurrentYear;
}
```